# Forcing Apache To Give All Info About $_SERVER

Tags: php, apache, superglobals

At the moment, I'm writing some php codes on localhost based on a training video. when I print_r my **$_SERVER**, It's almost bald. nothing to much. but the author of the training video, freely, uses **$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']** and others on **localhost** too, without getting **Undefined index** Error.

[image]

> "There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here"
>
> "You may or may not find any of the following elements in $_SERVER"

With these quotes, Are there any options in **httpd.conf** or other places, that allows apache to set those indices which normally cause **Undefined index** Error?

Comment: You mind showing what your `print_r($_SERVER)` actually gives you?

Comment: there is nothing to force.$_SERVER is a global variable.and what info u can get from it is in the manual.

Comment: Are you running PHP from the command line or a webserver? If you run your script from the command line then you obviously won't be provided CGI headers like `SERVER_NAME`, `SERVER_PORT` etc. - there's no connection for these variables to describe.

Comment: I have a suspicion, that you are running you script through command line php

Comment: I'm using PHP the way newbies use.
Make A PHP file in PHPStrom , Run It on Localhost through XAMPP(file copied on htdocs).